# Continuous function to describe a shifted Gaussian curve

Tags: functions, trigonometry

We have a set of numerical data that strictly follows Gaussian function (e.g. Fig. 1).  Suppose if we shift the left half of the Gaussian curve to to its right end (see Fig. 2), trend lines based on Gaussian function do not provide best-fits.

Figure Links: [Fig. 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv8Qi.jpg) [Fig.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZvmy.jpg)

Is there a an elegant continuous function to capture the trend shown in Fig. 2? Note that the Y-axis can vary though the X-axis remains the same (0-360).

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is your Gaussian function in figure 1 then the function in your second figure is

$$g(x)=\begin{cases} f(x) & 0 \leq x \leq 180 \\
f(360-x) & 180 \leq x \leq 360 \end{cases}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I am looking for a continuous function, the one you suggested is piece-wise continuous, if I am right.

Comment: @Stoka No, this is continuous; notice that $f(180)=f(360-180)$.